# Chrome connects fine to Rails server started with `rails s`, fails with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED during system specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I've got a `docker-compose` stack consisting of four services:

1. `rails`: a Rails app based on `ruby:2.7.2-alpine`
2. `db`: a Postgres database (`postgres:12.2`)
3. `selenium` a Selenium hub (`selenium/hub`)
4. `selenium-chrome`: a Selenium instance for debugging over VNC, based on `selenium/node-chrome-debug`

When I start up the stack, log into the `rails` container, and run `rails s`, I can connect to the `selenium-chrome` container over VNC, launch Chrome (via a `docker exec` command line), and navigate to `http://rails:3000` with no difficulty. (This works even if I start the server with `RAILS_ENV=test rails s`.)

When I run system specs, however, they all fail with Chrome unable to load any of the Rails app pages, always failing with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I added a `byebug` call before one of the failing `visit` calls, so I could try hitting the site manually with the in-container Chrome instance, and got this:

[image: chrome screenshot]

`curl` from within the Selenium container fails similarly:

```
root@6d92f4e4f0c0:/# curl -v http://rails:3000/
*   Trying 172.27.0.5:3000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.27.0.5 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to rails port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to rails port 3000: Connection refused
```

Is there a reason why during system tests the app would:

1. not be running, or
2. be running on the wrong port?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were two problems:

1. Capybara was configured (in `spec_helper.rb`) to talk to a remote server, rather than an in-process Rack application:

   ```rb
   Capybara.run_server = false  # <-- oops! actually, we DO want a server
   ```
2. With this line removed, Capybara started the application, but on a random port (see Avdi Grimm, “[Run Rails 6 System Tests in Docker Using a Host Browser](https://avdi.codes/run-rails-6-system-tests-in-docker-using-a-host-browser/)”).

The fix was to remove `run_server=false`, but also add the following lines to my Capybara config:

```rb
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'  # <-- could be "rails", but then tests *only* work in Docker
Capybara.server_port = 3000
```

Now Capybara starts a test server, and starts it on the port where the tests tell Selenium to find it.